# Activity starts itself randomly

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am coding app in android studio and I have multiple activities in my project. I dont use any Task manager I just change activity A to activity B , but after few seconds the application goes back to activity A. Sometimes it also happens when I am in activity A and application "refresh" this activity A again without any triggers.

I checked if there is mistake in manifest, activity classes or layouts. Everything seems to be OK

In logcat I get the following message whenever the problen occurs:

> D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf026b80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xea2aec70)

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
</activity>


<activity android:name=".BluetoothActivity">
</activity>
```

change login to bluetooth activity code

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, BluetoothActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
```

Comment: Show the `Manifest` file and your activity starting code please

Comment: i uploaded it up

Comment: use finishAffinity() instead of finish() may it work

Comment: I see LoginActivity, BluetoothActivity and Mainactivity. At which activity are you when it resets? Please add Code from the activity which closes

Comment: Sounds to me like you have some background activity that is calling `startActivity()` which brings the other `Activity` to the foreground. Either that or something is crashing so Android is returning to the previous `Activity`. To get more information about what is going on you should override the lifecycle methods (`onCreate(), onStart(), onResume()`, etc.) and add logging to those methods. Then you can see what is really happening.